# Date Validation Parameters

Tags: javascript

I have some older code that I am working on (not mine), specifically a date validation function. The user enters the date and the function checks whether the formatting and numbering is correct with `onBlur="validateDate(this.value)"`. If there is an issue found, the system will alert the user. However, there is a couple of things it doesn't take into account. For instance, you can type in characters for the date values and the system will accept it. The system will also accept different string lengths than what are intended for MM/DD/YYYY format (2/2/4). How can I easily modify the code to account for these parameters?

```
function validateDate(date_string)
    {
        if (date_string.indexOf('/') == -1)
        {
            alert("this date is not valid. Please enter a data in MM/DD/YYYY format");
            ErrorCount=1;
        }
        else
        {    
            if (date_string.indexOf(' ') >=0)
            {     
                alert("this date is not valid.  Please enter a data in MM/DD/YYYY format");
                ErrorCount=1;
            }
            else
            {
                var date_element=date_string.split('/');
                if(date_element[0] < 1 || date_element[0] > 12)
                {
                    alert("Month should be a value between 1 and 12");
                    ErrorCount=1;
                }
                if(date_element[1] < 1 || date_element[1] > 31)
                {
                    alert("Day should be a number between 1 and 31");
                    ErrorCount=1;               
                }
                if(date_element[2] < 1999 || date_element[2] > 2075)
                {
                    alert("The year is suspect");
                    ErrorCount=1;               
                }
            }   

        }
        if  (ErrorCount==1)
            {document.getElementById('release_date').focus(); }
        ErrorCount=0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather you can use in-built date function for this i.e.

```
new Date('2/2/4');
Output: Mon Feb 02 2004 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)


new Date('2/42/4');
Output: Invalid date
```

and then you can use functions like getFullYear(), getDate(), getMonth() etc to retrieve whatever you want.